# Execute tcl using sudo command

Tags: java, bash, tcl, sudo

I am using `tcl.lang.Interp.eval()` to execute a "hello world" tcl script. The command used to execute the script is something like this-

```
source /path/of/my/script.tcl
```

Now how do I execute the script as `sudo` user as we cannot execute `source` using `sudo` through java program?

Comment: 1.) What lib do you use? JTcl, TclJava or TclBlend? 2.) `source` loads the script in the same interp, so no external process is involved. 3.) If you want to do such things, invoke `sudo` directly.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn it is `tcljava.jar` that I use. Is there any other library which can serve my purpose i.e. execute `tcl` as `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

You can run *tclsh* (the “mothership” implementation of Tcl, written in C) from inside *sudo* just fine, or you can run a JVM which uses the TclJava library. However, *sudo* runs whole processes with elevated privileges and not just a library; you need to think in terms of creating a program that will do what you want, possibly with suitable arguments passed in.

FWIW, I'd start by trying:

```
sudo tclsh /path/of/my/script.tcl
```

That's going to be the simplest if it works; it's how *tclsh* is designed to be used (plus *sudo*). It's only unsuitable if the script requires access to an in-process JVM. If that's the case, you're probably going to have to write a small wrapper Java program.